# ng-Click does not works in ng-repeat table

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, angularjs, html

I have aproblem with angularjs ng-click does not works, my model is not updated.
When I want to read the model variables are empty.
I'm using bootstrap popup to show the model values(title, action is using for validation in a funciton inside controller).

HTML code

```
    <button ng-click="title = 'Add Project'; action='Add'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btnOpenPopUpForAdding" class="btn btn-default" title="Add new project"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

    <table class="table" id="tblProjects" style="display:none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>

                </th>
                <th>
                    Project Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Project Description
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="project in projects" >
            <td>
                <button ng-click="title = 'Update Project'; action='Update'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default" title="Update project">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>{{project.ProjectName}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>{{project.ProjectDescription}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.Partial("../ProjectView")
</div>
```

Partial view

```
<!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="txtProjectName">Project Name</label>
            <input ng-model="singleProject.ProjectName" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:65%" id="txtProjectName" placeholder="Type the project name" />
            <br />
            <label for="txtProjectDescription">Project Description</label>
            <textarea ng-model="singleProject.ProjectDescription" class="form-control" style="width:65%" id="txtProjectDescription" placeholder="Type the project description" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ThrowEvent()">Save</button>
            <button id="btnCancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller code

```
$scope.ThrowEvent = function () {
    if ($scope.action == 'Add')
        $scope.AddProject($scope.singleProject);
    if($scope.action == 'Update')
        $scope.UpdateProject($scope.singleProject);
    //if($scope.action == 'Delete')
}
```

Comment: How about `action='UpdateProject'`

Comment: ng-click for button Add is working (outside ng-repeat), but for Updating not (inside ng-repeat)

Comment: Action is shown as empty when i try to read from controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that ng-repeat creates separate child scopes. In your case `ng-click="title = 'Update Project'; action='Update'"` where `title` and `action` are assigned to the child scope, not the parent.

To fix this you must prefix your model in your controller, for example

`$scope.myActions = {title: 'Default Title', action: 'Default action'};`

Then you can change `ng-click="title = 'Update Project'; action='Update'"` to `ng-click="myActions.title = 'Update Project'; myActions.action='Update'"`

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` will create a new scope for each iteration.

`"title = 'Update Project'; action='Update'"` will execute successful, but it will write the values to the sub-scope of ng-repeat and is not visible by the controller.

To solve the issue you can create a data container in the controller

```
$scope.data = {};
```

and write to the container

```
ng-click="data.title = 'Update Project'; data.action='Update'"`
```